# Bash script string comparison error, can't figure out

Tags: bash

I fixed the code below so it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
out="$(cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch)"
if [[ "$out" == *OFF* ]];
then
    tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<ON
    echo "Nvidia card activated."
else
    tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF
    echo "Nvidia card disabled."
fi
```

This is made for activating or disabling my optimus card. I get an error on line 4:

```
./.bb: line 4: [0000:01:00.0 OFF: command not found
OFF
Nvidia card disabled.
```

I can read from it that it tries to execute the $out variable. Why?

Comment: You've made several changes to the question. Does the error still occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that there is at least 1 space between the brackets `[` / `]` and the actual variables; i.e.: change your code from

```
if ["$out" == "$is"];
```

to:

```
if [ "$out" == "$is" ];
```

And it should work.

The reason is that `[` is actually the "test" command in bash. Try on your prompt:

```
which [
```

and you should see something like:

```
/usr/bin/[
```

Also, `man [` to read more about syntax

(Note, since arguments are delimited by spaces, there needs to be a space between your 2nd variable and `]` as well. Test uses `]` as the terminating sentinel)

Comment: hmm.. I fixed it now, but there is a problem with the if statement. It never executes the ON part, only the OFF part.

Comment: I tried your command, Tristan, with sampson-chen's change and it works. Perhaps you are not getting the value you expect for one of your variables? Try adding this, `set -x`, right below your `#!/bin/bash` You can debug the output this way.

Comment: [[ 0000:01:00.0 OFF == \O\F\F ]] what is that supposed to mean, the \O\F\F